# Html ccs custom radio button right to left

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have been created custom radio button right to left
i used code from w3school
[custom radio button w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)
but it's not working as right to left
that's mean first circle of radio and next text

```css
.radioContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    user-select: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.radioContainer input {
    display:none;

}
.radioContainer .circle{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
.radioContainer:hover .circle{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.radioContainer input:checked + .circle{
    background-color: #2196fc;
}
.radioContainer input:checked + .circle:after{
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:50%;
    top:50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<label class="radioContainer">my text1
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="circle"></span>
</label>
<br/>
<label class="radioContainer">my text2
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="circle"></span>
</label>
```

I want to change direction of label or put  all the radio buttons on to div and set direction of div from right to left, but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `padding-left` to `padding-right` in `radioContainer` class.

And also change `left` to `right` in `.radioContainer .circle`

Your final CSS must be like this:

```
.radioContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    user-select: none;
    padding-right: 30px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.radioContainer input {
    display:none;

}
.radioContainer .circle{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
.radioContainer:hover .circle{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.radioContainer input:checked + .circle{
    background-color: #2196fc;
}
.radioContainer input:checked + .circle:after{
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:50%;
    top:50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```